# Keep the modified date of files extracted from the ZIP using PHP ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using `ZipArchive` to extract files from ZIP.

Here is the code I am using

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('test/');
    $zip->close();
}
```

It works fine but the last modified date of extracted files changes to current time.

How I can keep the original last modified date of the extracted files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it by using `mtime` value supplied by [ZipArchive::statIndex](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.statindex.php)

It changes the modified date of the extracted file after extraction.

Here is the final code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $filename = $mtime = $zip->statIndex(0)['name'];
    $zip->extractTo('test/');
    touch('test/'.$filename, $zip->statIndex(0)['mtime']); // Change the modified date of the extracted file.
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Actually this changes only the first file, (with index=0), you need to cycle all the files to apply to the whole zip

Answer (score 6):

I improved Badal's answer to apply to all the files in the ZIP (directories will still have the current timestamp):

```
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if($res === true) {
    $zip->extractTo($dataDir);

    for($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++){
        touch($dataDir . $zip->statIndex($i)['name'], $zip->statIndex($i)['mtime']);
    }

    $zip->close();
}
```

*`$dataDir` needs to end with a slash.*

Comment: I used this script and the directories timestamps _were_ updated as well (with PHP 7.3.12).

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50678) about this with a pull request to fix it, but it hasn't been applied yet

Answer (score 0):

In zip archives, the date and time are encoded in standard MS-DOS format (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). This means that date and time are according to the local time of the system that created the zip archive.

The mtime returned by statIndex assumes that the local time of the system that created the zip archive was UTC (GMT), which is rarely true.